# How to activate child theme in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have running website on wordpress. Now i want to do some changes on it. So theme developer said activate child theme, but i dont know how to do this. i want to activate chid theme without damage any content of main website.

Comment: Please, refer to the WordPress documentation and more specifically [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). If you have any difficulties, feel free to edit your question and state your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a blank theme with these 3 files

1. style.css
2. functions.php
3. screenshot.png (or .jpg) - it's optional but good practice

Add `-child` end of your theme folder. For example, your main theme name is `twentyninteen`. Add child theme folder `twentyninteen-child`. It's not required but recommended by WordPress. You can choose any folder name if you want.

In child theme's `style.css` add these on top of the file:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Ninteen Child
 Theme URI:    https://themesniper.com/twenty-ninteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty ninteen Child Theme
 Author:       Harun R Rayhan
 Author URI:   https://harunrrayhan.com
 Template:     twentyninteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, 
 Text Domain:  twentyninteenchild
*/
```

You can change any info from these details. In `Template: twentyninteen`, replace `twentyninteen` with your main theme's directory name.

And then you can add any changes in this theme. Read more about child theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/